# How do I mount a travan tape drive in Linux

Tags: linux, device, mount, floppy, mt

I have some old travan tapes that I'd like to read.  I bought an old Travan drive (HP colorado memory systems) from ebay. This drive originally connected to a floppy drive IDE connector.

Since my motherboard doesn't have a floppy connector, I bought a USB to floppy converter.  Now plugging the converter into the drive and connecting it to the PC,  I see this with lsusb:

Bus 006 Device 004: ID 0644:0000 TEAC Corp. Floppy

dmesg shows extensive output (below) including errors but the device appears to be mounting at /dev/sdc

So I tried:

```
$ sudo mt -f /dev/sdc rewind
mt: /dev/sdc is not a character special file
```

I'm not sure what to try next or how to mount the drive as a character special file.

dmesg output:

```
[ 1519.022625] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:200A.0006: HID++ 1.0 device connected.
[92341.221587] usb 6-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci-pci
[92341.416385] usb 6-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0644, idProduct=0000, bcdDevice= 2.00
[92341.416390] usb 6-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[92341.416393] usb 6-1: Product: TEACV0.0
[92341.416396] usb 6-1: Manufacturer: TEACV0.0
[92341.418527] usb-storage 6-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[92341.418983] scsi host7: usb-storage 6-1:1.0
[92342.461444] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TEAC     USB UF000x       0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[92342.462446] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[92342.493345] sd 7:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[92342.557416] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 2880 512-byte logical blocks: (1.47 MB/1.41 MiB)
[92342.589404] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[92342.589410] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 46 02 00
[92342.621405] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[92342.621416] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[92350.685241] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92350.685249] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92350.685255] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92350.685260] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92350.685264] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92350.685272] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92358.525066] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92358.525072] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92358.525075] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92358.525079] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92358.525081] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92358.525087] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92366.364914] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92366.364920] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92366.364925] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92366.364931] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92366.364935] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92366.364943] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92374.204771] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92374.204779] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92374.204784] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92374.204789] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92374.204793] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92374.204802] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92374.204834] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[92382.044607] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92382.044613] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92382.044617] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92382.044621] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92382.044624] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92382.044631] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92389.884476] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92389.884483] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92389.884488] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92389.884493] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92389.884497] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92389.884506] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92397.724317] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92397.724321] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92397.724325] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92397.724329] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92397.724331] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92397.724338] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92405.564185] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92405.564193] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92405.564198] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92405.564204] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92405.564208] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92405.564218] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92405.564247] Dev sdc: unable to read RDB block 0
[92413.436022] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92413.436030] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92413.436035] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92413.436041] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92413.436044] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92413.436053] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92421.275888] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92421.275896] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92421.275902] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92421.275907] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92421.275911] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92421.275920] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92429.051721] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92429.051726] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92429.051729] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92429.051733] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92429.051736] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 24
[92429.051743] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 3, async page read
[92436.891607] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92436.891614] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92436.891620] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92436.891626] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92436.891629] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92436.891638] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92436.891664]  sdc: unable to read partition table
[92437.083608] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[92438.395553] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92438.395561] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92438.395567] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92438.395572] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92438.395576] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92446.235399] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92446.235405] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92446.235410] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92446.235414] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92446.235417] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92446.235426] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92454.139242] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92454.139249] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92454.139254] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92454.139258] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92454.139262] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92454.139272] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92462.043098] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92462.043106] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92462.043111] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92462.043116] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92462.043119] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92462.043128] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92469.914965] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92469.914973] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92469.914979] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92469.914985] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92469.914988] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92469.914998] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92477.818813] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92477.818822] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92477.818828] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92477.818834] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92477.818838] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92477.818848] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92485.722657] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92485.722664] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92485.722669] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92485.722675] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92485.722679] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92485.722689] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[92493.626519] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92493.626527] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92493.626532] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92493.626538] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92493.626542] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 24
[92493.626551] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 3, async page read
[92495.098566] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92495.098573] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92495.098578] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92495.098583] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92495.098587] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 8
[92502.970335] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92502.970342] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92502.970348] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92502.970353] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92502.970357] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 8
[92502.970367] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 1, async page read
[92510.906161] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92510.906167] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92510.906172] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92510.906178] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 08 00 00 00
[92510.906181] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 128
[92510.906191] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 16, async page read
[92518.842035] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92518.842043] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92518.842048] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92518.842054] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 02 00 00 00
[92518.842058] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 2
[92518.842095] EXT4-fs (sdc): unable to read superblock
[92526.777879] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92526.777887] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92526.777892] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92526.777898] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 02 00 00 00
[92526.777902] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 2
[92526.777939] EXT4-fs (sdc): unable to read superblock
[92534.681729] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92534.681737] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92534.681742] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92534.681748] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 02 00 00 00
[92534.681751] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 2
[92534.681792] EXT4-fs (sdc): unable to read superblock
[92542.617574] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[92542.617581] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[92542.617587] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[92542.617592] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
[92542.617595] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[92542.617632] FAT-fs (sdc): unable to read boot sector
```

Comment: A USB to floppy converter is probably just not going to do the trick, you would need Travan tape drive software running on the chip in the converter, so it would know to create a USB tape drive subprofile instead of a floppy drive subprofile.

Comment: But Stack Overflow is the wrong place to ask questions about making hardware work with software written by other people.